# Travis-CI detects wrong trigger? Github send wrong hook?

Tags: github, travis-ci

## Travis-CI detects wrong trigger?

Travis detects wrong commit as trigger? Github send wrong hook? Where is mistake in my workflow?

### My workflow

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout -b feature-foo origin/master
 (edit, delete, commit…)
$ git push origin feature-foo:feature-foo

 (sometimes time passed)
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout -b feature-bar origin/master
 (edit, delete, commit…)
$ git push origin feature-bar:feature-bar
# Then problem happens!
```

I pushed only *feature-bar*, but travis detects *master* commit. Travis build history hides this commit, so this shows only #1 and #3.

I have two problems:

- Wrong detect as *master* commit, and sometimes fail
- Wrong detect spend actual build time

My repos:

- repos: https://github.com/sanemat/tsurapoyo
- travis: https://travis-ci.org/sanemat/tsurapoyo

Travis Build History
https://travis-ci.org/sanemat/tsurapoyo/builds
only show #1 and #3

#1

- branch: add-travis #=> valid
- http://github.com/sanemat/tsurapoyo/commit/74066d865a7ad564555d36696887490c46218a31
- https://travis-ci.org/sanemat/tsurapoyo/builds/3301289
- commit message: Add .travis.yml

#2

- branch: master #=> invalid!! This is not *master*
- http://github.com/sanemat/tsurapoyo/commit/68e4731259f1c9a89cae41e251f696f5ceb5c0c8
- https://travis-ci.org/sanemat/tsurapoyo/builds/3301291
- commit message: Add .travis.yml

#3

- branch: master #=> valid
- http://github.com/sanemat/tsurapoyo/commit/b3ab009ddc382ad5adce19f6f86d15803a5b8cb3
- https://travis-ci.org/sanemat/tsurapoyo/builds/3301317
- commit message: Merge pull request #1 from sanemat/add-travis

Answer (score 1):

The branch shown in #2 is the branch a pull request is sent against. We show slightly different details on Travis for builds that originated in a pull request and builds that are the result of normal branch pushes.

For branch pushes we show the branch that was pushed to, and for pull requests we show the branch the pull request was sent against.

The pull request is also not shown in the builds tab, it has its own tab in your repository on Travis: https://travis-ci.org/sanemat/tsurapoyo/pull_requests

Comment: Sometimes, in [github's pull request page](https://github.com/sanemat/tsurapoyo/pull/1), travis result is shown like: "Determining merge status — The Travis build is in progress (Details)" detects build #1 or #2 indefinite. Detecting #2 in pull request page is bug, I think.